# lightbox disappears of view from window resize in Android

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, mobile, lightbox

the lightbox is shown in the right position (top/left centered), but when users zoom; the lightobx stays in the same position (without considering the window/view has been resized/cropped),

You can [test this here](http://goo.gl/sd6bI) clicking in the blue button of the header

I am checking at the code of lightbox, and, i can see

```
$(window).bind('resize', $.proxy(function() {
          if (this.visible)
          {
            this.overlay.resize();
            if (!this.maximized) {
              this.movebox();
            }
          }
        }, this));
```

WHERE MOVEBOX() IS:

```
function(w, h) {
        var size   = { x: $(window).width(),      y: $(window).height() };
        var scroll = { x: $(window).scrollLeft(), y: $(window).scrollTop() };
        var height = h!=null ? h : this.esqueleto.lightbox.outerHeight();
        var width  = w!=null ? w : this.esqueleto.lightbox.outerWidth();
        var y      = 0;
        var x      = 0;

         //vertically center
        x = scroll.x + ((size.x - width) / 2);

        if (this.visible) {
          y = scroll.y + (size.y - height) / 2;
        } else if (this.options.emergefrom == "bottom") {
          y = (scroll.y + size.y + 14);
        } else {// top
          y = (scroll.y - height) - 14;
        }

        if (this.visible) {

          if (!this.animations.move) {
            this.morph(this.esqueleto.move, {
              'left' : x
            }, 'move');
          }

          this.morph(this.esqueleto.move, {
            'top'  : y
          }, 'move');

        } else {

          this.esqueleto.move.css({
            'left' : x,
            'top'  : y
          });
        }
      }
```

question is: how can I properly calculate new height and new with so the lightbox follows srcoll/zoom in android (and also in iphone it moves a bit)

Answer (score 0):

My answer at [move() element on window.resize() function not working on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608970/move-element-on-window-resize-function-not-working-on-android) might shed some light on the subject for you. I'm guessing you're running into some sort of problem with scrollLeft().

Sad times :(